# Upgrade from 12.10 to 13.04 affecting other systems

Tags: 12.10, grub2, dual-boot, upgrade, 13.04

I'm quite new to using Ubuntu. I have a dual-booted computer, running Windows 7 & Ubuntu 12.10. I'm planning to get an upgrade to 13.04. In terminal, I know the command is "do-release-upgrade". But, when I install it, will it leave my other systems alone? I'm expecting it will just add the option to boot into Ubuntu 13.04 when I turn on my computer?
So I would have the options:
Windows 7,
Ubuntu 12.10 &
Ubuntu 13.04

Correct? All in my GRUB menu.
Help is greatly appreciated, I just really want to make sure nothing will be harmed. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Although the upgrade should go without any problem you should back up your data first just in case. Upgrades can fail for any number of reasons. You should also read the release notes first.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes

Especially the "known issues" section

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/RaringRingtail/ReleaseNotes#Known_issues

There is no reason to believe the upgrade would affect windows.

Once you upgrade, you will no longer be able to boot 12.10 and there should not be an option to do so.

Comment: It's best to choose your best answer so as to close this thread

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a working dual boot (windows 7 and ubuntu 12.10) go ahead and upgrade.

12.10 will be upgraded to 13.04 thereby eliminating any previous version in GRUB. Think of 13.04 as a new 12.10

Also since GRUB is handling the master bootloader, nothing will happen to your current setup as your new setup after the upgrade will be:

-Ubuntu 13.04
-Windows 7

So go ahead and upgrade. GRUB really handles Windows 7 very well.

Hope this helps.